# How to transfer value from website to windows forms online?

Tags: selenium, textbox, webdriver, windows-forms-designer

I am creating an application on Windows Form and collided with a trouble. 
I am getting each second a value from a website by Selenium Webdriver, using XPath and recording it to my local string. I am getting value of a timer. It doesn't matter, it's comfortable to me to get it like a string.

So. I have a loop, which reading data from website and this string I put to TextBox each second too.

But I am not able to see an output of the textBox until my loop is run. I don't want to stop it.

I want to see values from a website online in my application. 
Do you have ideas how to refresh the form each second? 
I can provide my code if you need.

Thank you in advance, my guru!

```
   public static ChromeDriver GetDriver() {
       return new ChromeDriver();
      }

      public static void CheckGame(string URLevent) {
       while (GameIsRun) {
        GetInformation(GetDriver(), URLevent);
        GameIsRun = false;
       }
      }

      static void GetInformation(ChromeDriver driver, string URLevent) {
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URLevent);
       do {
        TimeOfGame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div/div/div//div/" + 
           "div[@class='headroom-wrapper']/div//div[3]/div")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
        Print print = new Print()
        print.Info(TimeOfGame);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }
       while (TimeOfGame != "90:00");
      }

      public partial class Form1: Form {
       public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Form form = new Form();
       }

       private static Form1 _form = null;
       public static Form1 Form {
        get {
         if (_form == null) {
          _form = new Form1();
         }
         return _form;
        }
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string eventId = tbEventID.Text; //this works vice versa. It's not my issue.
        string URLevent = "url..." + tbEventID.Text + "/";
        Program.CheckGame(URLevent);
       }
      }

      public class Print {
       public void Info(string TimeOfGame) {
        Form1.Form.tbTeam1.Text = TimeOfGame; 
        //my issue is here. I want to check result at TextBox each second! 
       }
      }
```

Comment: You should give code

Comment: Deal! One moment!

Comment: I gave my code. Check it, please!

Comment: Question is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement in your code

`TimeOfGame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div/div/div//div/div[@class='headroom-wrapper']/div//div[3]/div")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");`

is very **brittle**. You should use getText() method for extracting the inner text of HTML methods. Also, in order to locate webElement precisely,  it is preferred to use  focused relative Xpath over absolute Xpath.

Comment: Give me please a hint, why I am not able to set the value of TextBox from another class?